# Get the MAX date between a range

Tags: mysql, sql

I was searching for querys but i cant find an answer that helps me or if exit a similar question.

i need to get the info of the customers that made their last purchase between two dates

```
+--------+------------+------------+
| client | amt        | date       |
+--------+------------+------------+
|      1 |  2440.9100 | 2014-02-05 |
|      1 | 21640.4600 | 2014-03-11 |
|      2 |  6782.5000 | 2014-03-12 |
|      2 |  1324.6600 | 2014-05-28 |
+--------+------------+------------+
```

for example if i want to know all the cust who make the last purchase between
2014-02-11 and 2014-03-16, in that case the result must be

```
+--------+------------+------------+
| client | amt        | date       |
+--------+------------+------------+
|      1 | 21640.4600 | 2014-03-11 |
+--------+------------+------------+
```

cant be the client number 2 cause have a purchease on 2014-05-28,
i try to make a

```
SELECT MAX(date) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY client
```

but that only get the max of all dates,
i dont know if exist a function or something that can help, thanks.

---

well i dont know how to mark this question as resolved but this work for me
to complete the original query

```
SELECT client, MAX(date) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY  client
HAVING MAX(date) BETWEEN date1 AND date2
```

thanks to all that took a minute to help me with my problem,
special thanks to Ollie Jones and  Peter Pei Guo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something in this format, replace date1 and date 2 with the real values.

```
SELECT client, max(date) 
from table 
group by client
having max(date) between date1 AND date2
```

Comment: thanks, but if i do that will appear also the client number 2 cause have a date in 2014-03-12, and it cant appear cause have another purhcease on 2014-05-28, i need to know the cust who have their last purchase on the range if have a purhcease out of the range must not be displayed, i think is not that simple

Comment: @user3680275 have you tried it? This query should not return customer 2 since it filters only on max(date). Any purchases done before that will not be considered.

Answer (score 2):

There is more than one way to do this.  Here is one of them.

```
select * from 
(
select client, max(date) maxdate
from table
group by client ) temp
where maxdate between '2014-02-11' and '2014-03-06'
```

Answer (score 1):

This will allow you to grab the amount column of the applicable rows as well:

```
select t.*
  from tbl t
  join (select client, max(date) as last_date
          from tbl
         group by client
        having max(date) between date1 and date2) v
    on t.client = v.client
   and t.date = v.last_date
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to change the field "Date" to "TheDate" since date is a reserved word.  I assume you are using SQL?  My table name is Table1.  You need to group records:

SELECT Table1.Client, Sum(Table1.Amt) AS SumOfAmt, Table1.TheDate
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.Client, Table1.TheDate
HAVING (((Table1.TheDate) Between #2/11/2014# And #3/16/2014#));

Query Results:

Client  SumOfAmt    TheDate

1   21640          03/11/14

2   6792           03/12/14

You may want to get yourself a copy of MS Access.  You can generate SQL statements using their query builder which I used to generate this SQL.  When I make a post here I will always test it first to make sure it works! I have never written even 1 line of SQL code, but have executed thousands of them from within MS Access.

Good luck,

Dan